# Integral transformation change of variables

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus

Use the change of variables formula and an appropriate transformation to evaluate $\int \int_R xy \ dA$ , where R is the square with vertices $(0,0), (1,1),(2,0)$ and $(1,-1)$.

The answer is 0.

Can I do this ? Why ?
$$ \int_0 ^2 \int_{-1} ^1 xy \ dy \ dx = 0$$

Comment: No, you can not do this. You should plot the region to see what's wrong.

Answer (score 3):

You are not integrating the region $R$. The idea of the exercise is to  deform $R$ into a square with sides parallel to the axis in the plane by a counterclockwise rotation of an angle equal to $\frac{\pi}{4}$. The required transformation is then

$$(x,y)\mapsto (u,v)=\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}(x-y,x+y).$$

To finish the proof you need the formula for the [change of variables in multiple integrals](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiple_integral#Change_of_variables) recalling that the original integrand

$$f(x,y)=xy$$

in the new coordinates reads (I inverted the coordinate transformation given above)

$$\tilde{f}(u,v)=(u+v)(v-u)$$

Computing the determinant of the Jacobian of the coord. transofrmation the exercise is finished.